# Установить WebSocket в php

Tags: windows, php, websocket

Здравствуйте!
Как установить `websocket` в php на `windows 7`, поиск только выдает на `UNIX` системы.

Comment: не там копаете, вебсокет - это принцип передачи, а не программа

Comment: я имею ввиду, как сделать сие чудо, тобиш как и к чему подключить, что бы можно было с ним работать, ну там библиотеки, расширения тд.